# AWSSDK sample code to list S3 bucket items throwing errors

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services

New to using AWSSDK in Swift/Xcode. Just tyring to get the basic example Swift code to work to list items in an AWS S# bucket.

Cannot even get past first 2 sets of sample code without errors thrown

```
let client = try S3Client(region: "us-east-1")

let output = try await client.listBuckets(
    input: ListBucketsInput()
)
```

Xcode warns:

> Call can throw, but errors cannot be thrown out of a property initializer

on first line and

> Cannot use instance member 'client' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

on second line.

I've scoured online and cannot find any good resources for beginners trying to utilize the basic functions in AWSSDK for Swift.

Code examples from:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-swift/latest/developer-guide/getting-started.html#using-services-from-swift-code

Comment: Sounds like you have written this code inside an (unshown) property initializer (an init() method). How is your initializer declared?

Comment: Yeah, before this can be answered, the complete code needs to be seen. Are you literally just using the example code straight from the site, or are you following along doing the same things in your own code? It @jarmod is right that it looks like you're trying to throw out of a property initializer that you're not showing here.

Comment: i am literally copying sample code and following the steps exactly. Ive build over 100 Views with basic code probably a intermediate level developers o im SURE im misisng a few steps but ive soured the net theres NOTHING walkgin you through all the steps

Comment: This is curious. Those samples go through a long process to get published so there's no reason they shouldn't work as-is. Can you give me a link to the exact example you're using so I can try it again? It's been maybe three months since the last time I personally built any of the S3 examples.

Comment: I can also add that I've just now manually run the two versions of the `ListSamples` example provided in the AWS Swift SDK code examples, and both work fine for me. I'll keep an eye on this to see what you're specifically using so I can dial in on it.

Comment: OK, apologies but I am more a novice than I knew evidently but have a better understanding now of what i need.

I am trying to list files in an S3 bucket and eventually upload and do more with the new AWSSDK.

I have successfully gotten the sample code to work and more to list out objects (filenames) in an S3 bucket with the code below: However when i run the code outside the XCode IDE environment I understand I have to supply credentials, as XCode consumes the AWS keys from the local ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES I setup.

Comment: I want to manually pas sin the credentials/keys to the client object at runtime BUT cannot find ANYWHERE how to configure the AWSCLient object to include the credential keys (ACCESS & SECRET).

ANY help woud be greatly apprecaited as I cannot find anywhere the examples of how to do this, despite the documentation saying you can manually provide them to AWSCLient object.

dev code that works in IDE envrionment is ...